# My load balancer cannot communicate with my fargate instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I am learning some basics around VPCs, subnets, ECS (with Fargate) and things like that. I'm trying to deploy a very basic docker container, with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

This image works fine in local and when deployed using Fargate (I can see the logs in CloudWatch). The problem comes when the load balancer tries to contact my container. It does not pass the health check, so the instance gets destroyed and then created again, over and over.

The image is deployed to ECR and it's accessible by ECS (because I can see the services running for some seconds).

That's the problem, now I'm going to describe what I have done and what configuration and resources I have setup:

### VPC

- Id: vpc-0aca80a8ee7f636f6
- IPv4: 172.30.0.0/16

With the following route table associated:

- Routing table:

  - Routes:

    - 172.30.0.0/16 -> local
    - 0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-07bb57585a09fa127
  - Subnet associations:

    - subnet-09364cab61f5e5e04 / public-subnet-2 (172.30.12.0/24)
    - subnet-09fec2674273e56f2 / public-sn (172.30.10.0/24)

The internet gateway is attached to the VPC. I have also created a NAT attached to `subnet-09fec2674273e56f2 / public-sn`.

[image]

These are the subnets I have created inside that VPC (I'm only using the ones that are selected):

[image]

I think that's everything I have done to set up the network. I have also created an ECS cluster **without** creating a new VPC. I created a task definition, with the following configuration:

[image]

I'm aware that the number of tasks is 0, I changed it to avoid recreating instances all the time until I solve the problem.

This is the configuration of the load balancer:

[image]
[image]
[image]
And the target group:

[image]

Any idea why the request times out? Is more information needed?

#### Update 1

Security group of the task definition:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are security groups on the fargate tasks?

Comment: Added to the question! :D

Comment: You open port 8080 on fargate and I cannot see it in your sg. I think you can add your source sg-id in your sg.

Comment: OMG, you're right! LOL thanks a lot!!!!!!! please post that ask an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow port 8080 in your security group. You can use your sg-id in your security group.